# C++ class instance not initialized but no compile error, why

Tags: c++, initialization

My question is about the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Blob {
public:
    int age;
    void hello() { printf("hello\n"); }
};

void test_case() {
    Blob a;
    //a.hello();         //(1)
    cout << a.age << endl;
}

int main() {
    test_case();
    return 0;
}
```

if I comment out (1), it compile success. If uncomment out (1), compile error occur, e.g. in VS2017 it complains "using an unintialized local variable 'a'".

I've searched in search engine for a while and now only know the following 4 cases that the compiler will automatically help me define the default constructor:

1. a class member is an instance of a class (say B), and class B have defined default constructor
2. a class is derived from another class (say B), and B has defined default constructor
3. a class has virtual function
4. any combination of the previous 3 cases.

I'm curious that, if I comment out (1), will the compiler add a definition of constructor for the class `Blob`?

Comment: Uninitialized variables (including object member variables) will have an *indeterminate* value (it could be seen as random or garbage). Accessing this indeterminate value leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Undefined behavior is bad, and could do anything, from seemingly working fine to [summoning nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: `a.hello();` shouldn't change anything, the variable remains uninitialized. It just confuses your compiler for some reason. *"the following 4 cases that the compiler will automatically help me define the default constructor"* AFAIK, the default constructor is always generated, unless you add a custom constructor.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was just curious that why in VS2017, it complains me for "not initialize value error" but after I call `a.hello()` it doesn't complain any more. Well you are right, I should not write any UB. I've tested under MacOS's g++, it doesn't complain for not initializing value of `a`, whether I call `a.hello()` or not. Just  feel confuse and lose confidence in believing the C++ compilers.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, you are right, as I didn't use `=deleted`, c++ compiler will define the default constructor for my pasted code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact it has nothing to do with comment out or not `a.hello();`, `Blob` always has a [generated default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor), otherwise `Blob a;` won't compile.

(emphasis mine)

> If no user-declared constructors of any kind are provided for a class
>   type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare a
>   default constructor as an inline public member of its class.
>
> If the implicitly-declared default constructor is not defined as
>   deleted, it is defined (that is, a function body is generated and
>   compiled) by the compiler if odr-used, and **it has the same effect as a
>   user-defined constructor with empty body and empty initializer list**.

As the result, `a.age` is [default-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) to indeterminate value, any access to it (like `cout << a.age;`) leads to UB.

> 3) when a base class or a non-static data member is not mentioned in a
>   constructor initializer list and that constructor is called.
>
> otherwise, nothing is done: **the objects with automatic storage
>   duration (and their subobjects) are initialized to indeterminate
>   values**.

It depends on your intent; as the workaround you can add a user-defined default constructor.

```
class Blob {
public:
    int age;
    void hello() { printf("hello\n"); }
    Blob() : age(42) {}
};
```

Comment: Thank you for giving such a detailed answer. In fact, at the beginning when I met this question, I've read the Chinese version of that cpp reference page, not very carefully, and I didn't understand some translated words. I've open that English version page, and now feel 恍然大悟. Since there's no `delete` used in my pasted code, compiler will definitely define a default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 points here.

First is the Undefined Behaviour question. As you do not initialize age, it contains an indeterminate value which leads to UB if you use it (see songyuanyao's answers for more details on that). Adding an additional instruction does not change anything to that point.

Next is the compiler message. Compilers are not required to issue any warning facing UB. Yours is not specially consistent if it raises the error in only one case, but the programmer is supposed to never write UB. So you cannot really blame the compiler for not issuing the warning.

TL/DR: do not expect a C++ compiler to alway issue warning when you write incorrect code. Having  no warning is a necessary condition, but not a sufficient one.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out  that C++ compiler warnings are not enough.